# Does "dip" also mean "walk" in "dip out of view"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I heard in a movie description this line:

> Sharing his perspective, we watch her **dip out of view**.

The scene shows the character walking away until disappearing out of view. I couldn't find a definition of *dip* close to "to walk." Did I hear it wrong? I can't think of a similar-sounding word that would fit the context. I am putting the [audio clip here](https://clyp.it/fhnlstoj) (uploaded to an audio sharing site Clyp) for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You heard it correctly, but the relevant definition of **dip** is:

> **dip**, intransitive verb: to suddenly drop down or out of sight [(M-W)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dip)

The verb **dip** is referring to her dropping down out of sight from the perspective of the viewer, rather than her continuing to walk until she's out of sight.